# LINQ to XML Query to find all child values where parent element name like X C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So lets say I have a XElement that looks something like this

```
<Root>
     <ProductOne>
           <Size>Large</Size>
           <Height>2</Height>
     </ProductOne>
     <ProductTwo>
           <Size>Small</Size>
           <Type>Bar</Type>
     </ProductOne>
     <ProductThree>
           <Size>Small</Size>
           <Type>Crate</Type>
           <Color>Blue</Color>
     </ProductOne>
     <SomeOtherStuff>
           <OtherThing>CrazyData</OtherThing>
     </SomeOtherStuff>
</Root>
```

I want to query this data and get a IEnumerable string of the child values (I.E. Size, Type, Color, and a lot of other possuble attributes) of anything that is in a element with the word "Product" in it.

So My resulting list would look like

```
Large
2
Small
Bar
Small
Crate
Blue
```

Could someone tell me how to construct such a query using LINQ?

Comment: Any chance you could change your xml structure? Having `Product(Number)` as an element is not the cleanest solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just choose ProductOne as a general example. The actual Element names will be something like <MediaClasp> and im matching on the word Clasp

Comment: You've got a typo in the second and third product: `<Type>Bar</Height>`

Comment: Thanks! It's correct now. Foiled by copy and paste once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a lot of typos with your xml. Here is the correct version:

```
var xml = @"
<Root>
 <ProductOne>
       <Size>Large</Size>
       <Height>2</Height>
 </ProductOne>
 <ProductTwo>
       <Size>Small</Size>
       <Type>Bar</Type>
 </ProductTwo>
 <ProductThree>
       <Size>Small</Size>
       <Type>Crate</Type>
       <Color>Blue</Color>
 </ProductThree>
 <SomeOtherStuff>
       <OtherThing>CrazyData</OtherThing>
 </SomeOtherStuff>
</Root>";
```

Now, here is some linq magic you can do to get the values you want.

```
var list = XElement.Parse(xml)  //parses the xml as an XElement
    .Elements() //gets all elements under the "root" node
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Product")) // only selects elements that 
                                                        // start with "product"
    .SelectMany(x => x.Elements()) // inside of each of the "product" nodes, select
                                   // all the inner nodes and flatten the results 
                                   // into a single list
    .Select(x => x.Value) //select the node's inner text
    .ToList(); //to list (optional)
```

This will give you back your wanted list as a `List<string>`.

```
Large
2
Small
Bar
Small
Crate
Blue
```

Comment: Sorry i was writing the XML on the fly in the question window, it was not a real world scenario. But this works great, thanks!